# put value of <input type="file"> in a variable

Tags: javascript, html

How can I set the value of an input from a file type in a javaScript variable?
this is my input:

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: You mean the value of the input itsef (ie the filename) or the content of that file?

Comment: Not clear what your asking.  Do you really want to set a variable with the value of the input?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the value of text input field using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript)

Comment: The value of a `file` input can not be set programatically for security reasons. Getting the value after the user selects something, should be straight forward

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir not the file name. for example you choose a picture by my input. and i want to set its source in a java script variable and use that variable later.

Comment: @Tibrogargan yes. i want to set its source in a java script variable and use that variable later.

Comment: Doesn't matter, the technique is exactly the same.  That being said, you also have a `files` array on a file input that you can use, but for a single file input `value` is fine

Answer (score 2):

You can not set the value of a file input with Javascript.

The only way to set the value of a file input is by the user to select a file.

This is done for security reasons. Otherwise you would be able to create a Javascript that automatically uploads a specific file from the clients computer.

To get the value of a file `input`, use `document.getElementById("fileinputid").value`. However, it will give you the value mangled with something like `c:\fakepath\` to keep the details of the user's filesystem private.

Answer (score -3):

Setting the Value of the Input Element using JavaScript Variable

```js
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    var input = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    input[0].setAttribute("value", "c:\\yourPath\\");
    //The extra backslashes are to ignore each backslash

  });
```

```html
<input type="file">
```

Comment: Wondering if you tested this